# Action of matrix on symmetric products

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $M : V \to V$ is a linear map of a finite-dimensional vector space.  This induces a linear map $M_n : \operatorname{Sym}^n(V) \to \operatorname{Sym}^n(V)$ for any $n \geq 1$.

Is there a name for this I can look up?  I'm interested to find out basic things like what the eigenvectors, Jordan decomposition,... of $M_n$ look like, in terms of those of $M$.  (OK, the eigenvectors are pretty obvious, but I don't think the Jordan decomposition is quite as easy.)